# Swift code is adding unwanted nil data to core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to include reminders and also add to the users calendar into my app. However I am running into a problem, when I try to load the data saved in core data I am getting nil. I am only getting nil data after loading it a few times but it increases each time I reload the app.

addReminderToCalendar function

```
/*
 *
 *This function adds the reminder to the devices calendar and to the devices local storage
 *
 */
func addReminderToCalendar(newReminder : Reminder){
    print("adding reminder :" + newReminder.reminderName)
    /*print(newReminder.reminderDescription)
     print(newReminder.reminderDate)
     print(newReminder.reminderID)
     print(newReminder.reminderName)*/
    if(newReminder.reminderID != nil && newReminder.reminderDate != nil && newReminder.reminderDescription != nil && newReminder.reminderName != nil){
        //print("Adding Reminder to Calendar")
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate!
        let managedContext = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Reminders", in:managedContext!)
        let reminderDB = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
        //  print("Reminder ID :" + String(newReminder.reminderID))
        if(checkForReminder(newReminder) == -1){//Checking that the reminder is not already added
            print("addReminderToCalendar :")
            print(newReminder.reminderID)
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderID, forKey: "reminderID")
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderName, forKey: "reminderName")
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderDescription, forKey: "reminderDescription")
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderDate, forKey: "reminderDate")
            reminders.append(newReminder)
        }
        if (managedContext?.hasChanges)! {
            do {
                try managedContext?.save()
            } catch {
                //print(newReminder)
                NSLog("Error Here")
            }
        }
    }else{
        print("The reminder to be added was nil")
    }
}
```

loadReminder function

```
    /*
 * This function loads the reminders that have been stored in the device
 */
func loadReminders(){

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Reminders")

    let results = try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    storedReminders = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    print(storedReminders.count)
    //print(storedReminders[0].value(forKey: "reminderID"))
    if (storedReminders.count > 0){
        for index in 0 ... storedReminders.count - 1{
            print("Loading reminder with ID : ")
            print(storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderID"))
            print("Loading reminder with Name : ")
            print(storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderName"))

            if(storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderID") != nil && storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderName") != nil && storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDescription") != nil && storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDate") != nil){ //checking that the values are not null
                let loadedReminder = Reminder()
                loadedReminder.reminderID = storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderID") as! Double
                loadedReminder.reminderName = storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderName") as! String
                loadedReminder.reminderDescription = storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDescription") as! String
                loadedReminder.reminderDate = (storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDate") as! NSDate) as Date!
                reminders.append(loadedReminder)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

reminder Class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class Reminder :UICollectionViewCell{

   var reminderDate: Date!
   var reminderDescription: String!
   var reminderID: Double!
   var reminderName: String!

}
```

**EDIT**
I have added to my load reminders the following lines, This is to stop the core data being filled with nil values.
                }else{
                    //delete this reminder
                    managedContext.delete(storedReminders[index] as NSManagedObject)
                    print("deleted data")
                }
So my loadReminders function now looks like this

/*
 * This function loads the reminders that have been stored in the device
 */
func loadReminders(){

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Reminders")

let results = try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

storedReminders = results as! [NSManagedObject]
print(storedReminders.count)
//print(storedReminders[0].value(forKey: "reminderID"))
if (storedReminders.count > 0){
    for index in 0 ... storedReminders.count - 1{
        print("Loading reminder with ID : ")
        print(storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderID"))
        print("Loading reminder with Name : ")
        print(storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderName"))

        if(storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderID") != nil && storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderName") != nil && storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDescription") != nil && storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDate") != nil){ //checking that the values are not null
            let loadedReminder = Reminder()
            loadedReminder.reminderID = storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderID") as! Double
            loadedReminder.reminderName = storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderName") as! String
            loadedReminder.reminderDescription = storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDescription") as! String
            loadedReminder.reminderDate = (storedReminders[index].value(forKey: "reminderDate") as! NSDate) as Date!
            reminders.append(loadedReminder)
        }else{
                //delete this reminder
                managedContext.delete(storedReminders[index] as NSManagedObject)
                print("deleted data")
            }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating a new `Reminders` instance and adding it to the `NSManagedObjectContext`

```
let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Reminders", in:managedContext!)
let reminderDB = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
```

Then you check if it's already added with:

```
if(checkForReminder(newReminder) == -1)
```

This is where I think the issue is. You have already added the `Reminders` instance to your context! So `managedContext?.hasChanges` will be `true`.

There are changes to the context and these `Reminders` will be saved with all your entities attributes with their default values. I assume they default to `nil`.

This should fix it, although there's parts of your code I can't see so take it with a grain of salt...

```
func addReminderToCalendar(newReminder: Reminder) {
    if(newReminder.reminderID != nil && newReminder.reminderDate != nil && newReminder.reminderDescription != nil && newReminder.reminderName != nil) {
        if(checkForReminder(newReminder) == -1) {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate!
            let managedContext = appDelegate?.managedObjectContext
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Reminders", in:managedContext!)
            let reminderDB = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderID, forKey: "reminderID")
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderName, forKey: "reminderName")
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderDescription, forKey: "reminderDescription")
            reminderDB.setValue(newReminder.reminderDate, forKey: "reminderDate")
            reminders.append(newReminder)

            if (managedContext?.hasChanges)! {
                do {
                    try managedContext?.save()
                } catch {
                    NSLog("Error Here")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("The reminder to be added was nil")
    }
}
```